# How to display List <string>[] in Listbox List? [c#]

Tags: c#, mysql, listbox

So i have this class. DeltaDataConnection.cs, inside, is an internal void, nested in that i have this list function

```
public List<string>[] Select()
{
    string xSQL = "SELECT * FROM `hangout_user`";
    // create a list.
    List<string>[] HANGOUT_USER_LIST = new List<string>[4];
    HANGOUT_USER_LIST[0] = new List<string>();
    HANGOUT_USER_LIST[1] = new List<string>();
    HANGOUT_USER_LIST[2] = new List<string>();
    HANGOUT_USER_LIST[3] = new List<string>();
    // open connection
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        MySqlCommand xSQL_CMD = new MySqlCommand(xSQL, xCONN);
        MySqlDataReader xSQL_READ = xSQL_CMD.ExecuteReader();
        while (xSQL_READ.Read())
        {
            HANGOUT_USER_LIST[0].Add(xSQL_READ["userid"] + "");
            HANGOUT_USER_LIST[1].Add(xSQL_READ["username"] + "");
            HANGOUT_USER_LIST[2].Add(xSQL_READ["password"] + "");
            HANGOUT_USER_LIST[3].Add(xSQL_READ["email"] + "");
        }
        xSQL_READ.Close();
        this.CloseConnection();
        return HANGOUT_USER_LIST;
    }
    else
    {
        return HANGOUT_USER_LIST;
    }
}
```

In a form called UserAccountList.cs i have a listbox called xUSERLIST.

I would like to get the contents of the code i have here, to display in each item in the listbox, the item in the database. my connection and disconnection is handled separately.

Please accept my apologies if this has been asked or answered before.

Comment: Any reason you're using an array of lists of arrays instead of a list of a class?

Comment: Since each item in the array is a list, how would you want to display it? jus the username? or also the password, email, and id?

Comment: no reason, just it seemed to work for what im intending it to do, and i was going for individual display. usernames in one listbox, passwords in another. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, it seems i had a error in my code. (hindsight).

```
// to make it work i had to move

List<string>[] HANGOUT_USER_LIST = new List<string>[4];

// to outside the constructor of the class, and make internal.

public List<string>[] Select()
{
// had to move it from inside here. to above it ^^^
}

// then in the form im using with the listboxes in i had to make this call.

xUSERLIST.DataSource = DeltaDataInterface.HANGOUT_USER_LIST[1];
xPASSLIST.DataSource = DeltaDataInterface.HANGOUT_USER_LIST[2];
xMAILLIST.DataSource = DeltaDataInterface.HANGOUT_USER_LIST[3];
xUIDLIST.DataSource = DeltaDataInterface.HANGOUT_USER_LIST[0];

// [0] gets the userid
// [1] gets the usernames
// [2] gets the passwords
// [3] gets the email.
```

that was it. job done.